# How to use vue element class from JQuery?

Tags: jquery, vue.js

ListComponent.vue

```
<button class="add">Button</button>
```

home.html

```
$('.add').on('click',function() {
   alert('Add');
});
```

Alert not show. How Can I get that class?

Answer (score 2):

You can directly do it in Vue, but if you wanted to use jQuery then you can write the jQuery code in the `mounted` or `created` hook. Also you can use the jQuery code in the methods as well.

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  mounted () {
    $('.add').on('click',function() {
      alert('Add');
    });  
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <button class="add">Button</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't use jquery .. it's easy to solve in vuejs

```
<button @click="alert('Add')">Button</button>
```

Comment: While I agree with you that Vue.js has its own event handlers, sometimes one has to use a 3rd party library based on jQuery, and thus needs proper solutions to his needs.

Comment: @Narxx There are proper ways to do this with jQuery or vanilla JS but they should invlove Vue refs and cleanups on unmount where possible. Loosely coupling the code to an element with `.add` selector anywhere on the page at arbitrary moment of time is the way to make the app buggy, leaky and hard to maintain, something that jQuery code is famous for.

Comment: @Hussam I'd upvote but this `alert=('Add')` is a mistake.

Comment: @Estu No matter if it shows an error or not but this is the correct way to add events to items using vuejs..

Comment: What I want to say is that any method can be call by simply writing its name and writing it in the methods section

Comment: Please, check your post again. It actually probably won't show an error, but this is a mistake, `alert=('Add')`. It should be `alert('Add')`.

Comment: Don't worry, I fixed it.
Thanks for your concern.